# Confidence interval interpretation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Im with a doubt about calculation and interpretation of confidence intervals.

I have a dataset that has some response times measurements from some requests send to some servers. And I want to calculate confidence intervals for this response time variable. This variable is in miliseconds.

I read that we should use a t-table to calculate confidence intervals, but Im using SPSS and I went to the "explore" menu and I selected "Descriptives" with 95% confidence interval.

And I get this results:

```
Mean: 904,73

95% confidence interval: Lower Bound: 900,48

                         Upper Bound:  908,98
```

My first doubt is: Using spss for this calculation we dont need to use the t-table right?

And the main doubt is about the interpretation of this value. This means what? If we measure again the response times of the requests in the same scenario the values will be in that values(900,48 908,98) with 95% confidence? Sorry, maybe this is a basic question but Im not understanding well the meaning of this confidence interval values.

Response time stats:

```
Standard Deviation: 1602
Variance: 2568399
Kurtosis: 37194
Skewness: 335900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your sample size, the distribution may be approximately normal which would allow you to use the Standard Normal Probabilities Table (which has critical z numbers).
Interpretation:
We are 95% confident that the true mean value of server response time is between 900,48 and 908,98 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this case the response time is not a normal distribution.

Comment: Since the sample size of 100 is greater than 30, you could use the Central Limit Theorem to assume that the distribution is approximately Normal

Comment: Im not understanding, as you can see with the stats above the distribution is not normal.

Comment: The interpretation still stays the same though, it’s just the calculation method that may change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for exemple with confidente interval we also can say that if we measure again some response time of a request the mean will be between 900,48 and 908,98 with 95% confidence?

Comment: You cannot say that because a confidence interval is making an inference regarding the true mean, i.e. the mean of all response times ever.  If you were to take a bunch of samples and find the confidence interval for all of them, 95% of those intervals would contain the true mean.  But the confidence interval you have now has no relation to the sample mean of different trial, so it would be incorrect to say the mean of another sample would be between 900,48 and 908,98.